# Difference between className and style-component in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Why should I use styled-components if having a className against an element does the work of styling?

Applied style :

```
h2.subTitle{
  font-size: 2em;
  color: blue;
}
```

Element to be styled using className :

```
<h2 className="subTitle">Gucci Snakes </h2>
```

Using styled component :

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
const Subtitle = styled.h2`
  font-size: 2em;
  color: blue;
`;
<Subtitle>Gucci Snakes</Subtitle>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs,

> styled-components generates unique class names for your styles. You never have to worry about duplication, overlap or misspellings.

This helps with regards to class/style name collision.

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#motivation

Answer (score 0):

It's used because of readability, classNames might work well, but you don't love them that much when you have 1 or 2 css files with 500 rows, also, the structure of styled components is similar to sass.

For more examples and info you can click [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/05/styling-components-react/) , [here](https://devrecipes.net/styled-components-pros-and-cons/) and [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/7-feature-rich-alternatives-to-styled-components/)